# Flot Chart pan range

Tags: jquery, flot

I have a fairly simple chart

```
    var d1 = [['A', 5], ['B', 7], ['C', 8], ['D', 9], ['E', 0], ['F', 10], ['G', 5], ];

    $.plot(".appointments_chart", [d1],
    {
        xaxis: {
            mode: "categories",
            tickLength: 0,
            panRange: [null, null]
        },
        yaxis: {
            panRange: false
        },
        pan: {
            interactive: true
        }
    });
```

What I want is when the initial chart is displayed there are only three points on the X Axis, C, D & E and the user can pan forwards or backwards to see the others. Is this possible?

Comment: Ok, it seems like I can do it with the xaxis min/max values if they are a number or date.

Answer (score 1):

my way of getting it is like this...

```
var d1 = [['C', 8], ['D', 9], ['E', 0]];
var options = {
    xaxis: {
        mode: "categories",
        tickLength: 0,
        panRange: [null, null]
    },
    yaxis: {
        panRange: false
    },
    pan: {
        interactive: true
    }
}
$.plot(".appointments_chart", d1, options );

// something big happened, let's add them all..
var d2 = [['A', 5], ['B', 7], ['F', 10], ['G', 5]];
$.plot(".appointments_chart", $.merge(d1,d2), options );
```

Comment: I tried that but the second plot just override the first one so I end up with all the points on the screen. I only ever want 3 to show and I can pan to the rest.

Comment: Not really, do I need to add the new data dynamically when panning? I am not sure what the 'something big happened' means.

Comment: not to be rude, but I find your comment funny... hmmm... `// something big happened, let's add them all..` this line, and the lines after are just example... you could bind a click event(or any event) and insert those lines... don't take this answer as a whole cause I don't really know your whole application/program codes...

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is load all the data initially but then in the initial view only display a subset. Then using the built in pan functionality they will be able to go left or right the see additional data. I am not sure how click events come into it, I need to bind a click to the panning? It doesn't seem like that would be a smooth user experience.